# This webpage has a redirect loop - php

Tags: php

Got a simple form on my index.php page that when submitted is processed on my post.php page.

**index.php**

```
    <form id="form" action="post.php" method="post">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"/> <br>
    Gender:<br>
    <input type="text" name="gender"/> <br>
    Age:<br>
    <input type="number" name="age" min="1" max="99"/> <br>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Input">
    </form>

<div class="data">
    <?php
        include ('post.php');
        foreach ($result as $row) {
        echo $row['name']  . " ";
        echo $row['gender'] . " " ;
        echo $row['age']  . "<br>" . " ";
        }
    ?> 
</div>
```

**post.php**
Below is the code for my post.php page, at the top is my header but i keep getting the same error when i submit the form.

```
<?php

header("Location: index.php");
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('sqlite:mydb.sqlite3');
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
             name VARCHAR(30),
             gender VARCHAR(30),
             age INTEGER)"
             );

if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name, gender, age) VALUES (:name, :gender, :age)");
  $stmt->execute(array(':name' => $_POST['name'], ':gender' => $_POST['gender'],':age' => $_POST['age']));

  $title = $_POST['name'];
  $message = $_POST['gender'];
  $age = $_POST['age'];
}

    $result = $dbh->query('SELECT * FROM test');

    $dbh = null;
}
    catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo $e->getMessage();
}       
?>
```

Comment: First you need to show us how you're causing the infinite redirect. Is index.php redirecting to post.php and post.php redirecting to index.php....because if you're really only moving to post.php when user clicks submit, this shouldn't be happening.

Comment: Only redirect when $_POST is set?

Answer (score 3):

Inside `index.php` you are `include`-ing the `post.php` file which immediately forwards you back to `index.php`.

You need to make the forwarding in `post.php` conditional or you need to rework your logic.

Comment: When placing my header inside my If statement it seems to work fine, is that bad practice?

Comment: @daniel, Placing a header in if-statements is fine. You just have to make sure not to print anything to the output before setting the headers.